# Expo android api target level 28 change to 29

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo version 37. I built an standalone app to be uploaded on play store. When I tried uploading the apk file. I got the error:

> expo your app currently targets api level 28 and must target at least api level 29

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Run `expo upgrade` and then re-build your Android standalone app using `expo build:android -t apk`

Comment: expo upgrade then npm install then expo buil

Comment: Running `expo upgrade` at the time might upgrade it to the most recent version at that time (38) but I think if someone runs that command now it might upgrade to the most recent version which as I am righting is 40. I would recommend using this command to specify the version you wish to upgrade to:
`expo update version_number` e.g `expo update 39.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Expo team is aware of the issue as stated [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/9446) and looking to fix this week.

Comment: This change has been deployed to SDK38 Android builders on August 5th, 14:38 UTC.

Must rebuild for it to target level 29

Answer (score 0):

you must upgrade to expo SDK38 , and it works now !

If your SDK is 37.
follow this  [upgrade expo](https://dev.to/expo/expo-sdk-38-is-now-available-5aa0)